# React Native TextInput and FlatList capturing onPress of ListItem

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-listview, react-native-flatlist, react-native-text

So I am trying to create an Autocomplete Search Box having 2 sibling views TextInput and FlatList (which is only displayed when `this.state.data.length> 0`) so my render function is given below : -

```
 renderItem = ({ item }) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity 
             onPress={(item) => {/* do something here */}}>
             <Text>{item.key}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        }

render(){
  return (
   <View>
     <TextInput />
     {this.state.data.length > 0 && 
       <FlatList 
       data={this.state.data}
       renderItem={this.renderItem} />}
   </View>);
}
```

The problem is when I click on the list item the first click triggers the `onEndEditing` callback of the `TextInput` and then the second click triggers the `onPress` of the `TouchableOpacity` of the list item.

How can I trigger the onPress of the list item on the first click please?

[image: demo gif]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an active [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13365) in react-native.

In the meantime, you can try handle `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` property in a `ScrollView` instead.

```
return (
        <ScrollView
            style={ styles.flex }
            automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={ false }
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
            contentInset={{ 'bottom':20 }}
            keyboardDismissMode='on-drag'
            >
            <View>...</View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
```